# How to limit the rotation of a gesture event?

Tags: actionscript-3, rotation, gesture

I have a dial that I want to rotate 120 degrees clockwise and anti clockwise. I dont want the dial to go past either point.

It needs to be a touch gesture also so it can be dragged by the user.

Any ideas? Is there a way to limit the Transform gesture rotation?

Ive tried conditions but nothing seems to work?

```
dial_mc.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ROTATE, rotateDial);

function rotateDial(e:TransformGestureEvent):void
{   
dial_mc.rotation += e:rotation
}
```

Comment: Forgot to add this is writing for AS3! ..Doh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try something like this:

```
dial_mc.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ROTATE, rotateDial);

function rotateDial(e:TransformGestureEvent):void
{   
  dial_mc.rotation += e:rotation
  if(dial_mc.rotation > MAX_ALLOWED_ROTATION) dial_mc.rotation = MAX_ALLOWED_ROTATION;
  if(dial_mc.rotation < 0 ) dial_mc.rotation = 0;
}
```